# Android ListView background color change

Tags: android, listview, background

I have ListView and I want to change currently active row to be different color.

Currently I have this:

```
rowView.setBackgroundColor( 0xFF0000FF ); // make blue bg
```

And it works as expected.

However there is one "philosophical" problem - since I use all default color schemes, what color I should use? Blue is poor example, because android scheme may be dark or light or completely custom.

Things I have in mind could be inverse color, sightly similar color (say 20% darker) or probably same color, but with some effect.

Must work on Android 2.2+

Edited:

Solution I am looking for is more something like this:

```
int x = this.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright);
listViewItem.setBackgroundColor(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know this is a color then you can try

```
    ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) button.getBackground();
```

And if you're on Android 3.0+ you can get out the resource id of the color.

```
    int colorId = buttonColor.getColor();
```

Then, do the following:

```
    int red = Color.red(colorId);
    int blue = Color.blue(colorId);
    int green = Color.green(colorId);
    double percent = 400;
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb((int)(red * percent/100),
        (int)(blue * percent/100),(int)(green * percent/100)));
```

Note making the color higher brightens the color, and a lower number darkens the color.

Comment: The point is that 10% lighter/darker is a hack. Is much better to use solid color, but I don't know the colors and do not know what color I should use? If I use blue, this will be wrong if whole ListView is blue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function to calculate colors darker or brighter see [Brighter/Darker function](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-generate-lighter-darker-color/). Is in javascript but is easy to translate to java

Comment: Happy to help, but if you think that was useful, the best way to thanks is upvote and or accept